# Show recent posts in different divs

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have 100 posts. I want to show 5 of the most recent posts on my homepage, but they will be scattered over the page.

I have tried adding the code attached, however this shows just the first.

```
            <div class="home-right">

                <div class="tiles">

                <?php // Display blog posts on any page @ https://m0n.co/l
                    $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('posts_per_page=1' . '&paged='.$paged);
                    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="tile" style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">

                        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Does this `posts_per_page=1` have anything to do with it?

Comment: This code I am duplicating for all 5 divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query limits the posts to only one.
If you repeat that same code 5 times, you will get 5 times the same one. As a simple modification, try to increase the pagination.

So in your first query:

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=1' . '&paged=1');
```

In your second query:

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=1' . '&paged=2');
```

Comment: Thats exactly it, I knew it was something simple. Thanks Ingo!